# Display Database data

Tags: php

I have typed variaties of this code and it doesn't display.
I manage to get another page to display but this one won't display at all.
I am trying to create a page a php file to friendly view Database content, Update , delete and add content if need be.

But first I need to be able to display the content before I can get the rest of the code.

And I did try adding the code for updating =, deleting and adding data from a similar display but to no success.
Your Help please?
No errors shown, its just a blank after the 'th' content tags.

I have tested till which line it compiles until, not sure if that helps. 
just fyi.

Sometimes it mentions it does not find database, sometimes but seldom. Don't know why but it is led to the correct source.

```html
 <?php
            require 'config.php';
            
            $con = mysql_connect( $db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
            
            if ($con->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
            }//else { echo 'it works'; }

            echo '<table>';
            echo '  <tr>';
            echo '      <th>';
            echo '          Comment';
            echo '      </th>';
            echo '  </tr>';
            
            $myData = "SELECT * FROM demo ";
            $res = mysql_query($myData,$con);
// especially not working after this line.
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        echo '  <tr>';
        echo '      <td>';
        echo '          <input type=text name=ID value="';
        echo                $row["ID"];
        echo '          "/>';
        echo '      </td>';
        echo '      <td>';
        echo '          <input type=text name=ID value="';
        echo                $row["Name"];
        echo '          "/>';
        echo '      </td>';
        echo '      <td>';
        echo '          <input type=text name=ID value="';
        echo                $row["Org"];
        echo '          "/>';
        echo '      </td>';
        echo '      <td>';
        echo '          <textarea name=Comment value="'.$row["Comment"].'"></textarea>';                        
        echo '      </td>';
        echo '      <td>';
        echo '           <input type=submit value=Update name=UpBut id=UpBut/>';
        echo '           <input type=submit value=Delete name=DelBut id=DelBut/>';
        echo '      </td>';
        echo '  </tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';

            $conn->close();
```

Comment: Please do not use the _deprecated_ mysql functions for the love of God.

Comment: You are opening an table not closing it, and then putting div's in it. Some Browsers may blank the div's. Consider using the real Table-schema : http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html

Comment: that wasn't the problem. its fine, now the comment won't show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using the deprecated mysql functions. 
Instead of:

```
$res = mysql_query($myData,$con);
```

Pass the `$con` before:

```
$res = mysqli_query($con, $myData);
```

This is definitely wrong:

```
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
```

Correct way:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
```

Try this:

```
<?php

 require 'config.php';
 /*
 $db_host = "localhost";
 $db_username = "yourusernamehere";
 $db_password = "yourpasswordhere";
 $db_name = "yourdbnamehere";           
 */
    $con = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }


            echo '<table>';
            echo '  <tr>';
            echo '      <th>';
            echo '          Comment';
            echo '      </th>';
            echo '  </tr>';

            $myData = "SELECT * FROM demo";
            $res = mysqli_query($con, $myData);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                    echo '<div id="main">' . '<p>';
                    echo $row["Comm"]; . '<br>';
                    echo $row["Name"]; . '<br>';
                    echo $row["Company"]; . '</p>';
                    echo "</div>";
            }

         ?>
```

> Notice: Study mysqli or PDO. The proper closing of `</table>` tag is
>   up to you as I don't know that else you might have afterwards.

Comment: This data won't display echo '      <td>';
            echo '          <textarea name=Comment value="'.$row["Comment"].'"></textarea>';                        
            echo '      </td>';